# Change HTTP port for KeyClock 21

Tags: keycloak

I'm trying to setup a keyclock server using 21.1.1 but want to change the HTTP away from 8080.  Where do I put the configuration now?

Comment: are you on standalone or clustered mode ?

Comment: Just running up a dev instance.  So standalone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set using using command Line or Environment variable

**CLI**: --http-port

**Env**: KC_HTTP_PORT

Ex : `sh kc.sh start-dev --http-port=9999`

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add "http-port" into the keyclock.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this `compose.yml` file. You should change the port number.

```yaml
version: '3'
    
    volumes:
      postgres_data:
          driver: local
      keycloak:
          driver: local
    
    services:
      postgres:
          image: postgres
          container_name: KEYCLOAK-DB
          restart: always
          volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
            POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: keycloak
      keycloak:
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
          container_name: KEYCLOAK
          restart: always
          volumes:
            - ./certs/fullchain.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.crt"
            - ./certs/privkey.pem:/etc/x509/https/tls.key
          ports:
            - 9445:8080
          environment:
            KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres/keycloak
            KC_DB_PORT: 5432
            KC_DB_DATABASE: keycloak
            KC_DB_USER: keycloak
            KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
            KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: keycloak
            KC_HTTP_ENABLED: "true"
            KC_HTTPS_ENABLED: "false"
            KC_PROXY: edge
            KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /etc/x509/https/tls.crt
            KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /etc/x509/https/tls.key        
            KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
          entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build --db postgres && /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start --optimized"]
          depends_on:
            - postgres
```